# Invalid Identifier for column showing in schema

Tags: vb.net, oracle

I am having trouble querying a column in an Oracle view that shows up when I pull the schema. In fact, it appears as column number 2 when I list it out.

The error indicates ORA-00904 invalid identifier, which from what I have read says the column name I am referencing is incorrect, but I have copied the name directly from Oracle Developer, MSAccess, and the datareader.Schema, all of which appear to have no issues getting to that column.

If I query the column just using a linked table in MSAccess the data also comes right up. All of the examples I have seen referencing a similar issue in which the field is incorrectly typed, which though I acknowledge is still a possibility, seems unlikely in this case given the direct copy from the column list as mentioned.

Other solutions mention putting the name in double quotes, which I am uncertain how to do in VB.NET or if it is even necessary.

Code below:

```
'Open And Query 
oledbCon.ConnectionString = strCon
oledbCon.Open()
oledbCom.Connection = oledbCon
oledbCom.CommandType = CommandType.Text
oledbCom.CommandText = "SELECT AREA_CODE FROM CSITAPPS.DAYSIN_1057"
oledbda.SelectCommand = oledbCom
oledbda.Fill(gdt)
```

[image: table]

Comment: What happens if you do SELECT * ?

Comment: SELECT * returns the entire table with that column and data. Putting a ; at the end produces a syntax error. The provider right now is MSDAORA, I'm not sure how to point the provider to the Oracle provider.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to find a solution working with a co-worker for a couple days. The issue stems from the fact that Oracle Column references are Case Sensitive. Because of this the double quotations were required, which is tricky for VB.net given quotation marks indicate and encapsulate String entries. The solution was to break the string and concatenate chr(34) into it. That in combination with ensuring that the column reference case matched what was in the table it came right up.

```
"SELECT " & Chr(34) & "Area_Code" & Chr(34) & " FROM CSITAPPS.DAYSIN_1057 ORDER BY " & Chr(34) & "Area_Code" & Chr(34) & " DESC;"
```